# Need help for SQL Query SQLserver or Access

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access

I have a datagrid:

[image]

and I want to list if `logo=true` or `chair=true` or `color=true`, but `name IS NOT NULL` values.

I tried:

```
SELECT 
    name,
    logo,
    chair,
    color 
FROM 
    Mytable 
WHERE 
    logo = True OR chair = True OR color = True 
    AND name IS NOT NULL
```

But this query lists all the columns.

I know my query is bad, but I can not find error.

How to fix this problem?

Post edit here my full code:

```
  Try
        Dim dt As New DataTable()
        Dim con As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source='" & Application.StartupPath & "\db.mdb';")
        Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand("Select * from table WHERE (chair = 'true' or color = 'true' or logo = 'true') and name is not null", con)
        Dim adap As New OleDbDataAdapter(cmd)
        adap.Fill(dt)
        DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
        DataGridView1.Columns(0).HeaderText = "Name"
        DataGridView1.Columns(1).HeaderText = "Logo"
        DataGridView1.Columns(2).HeaderText = "Chair"
        DataGridView1.Columns(3).HeaderText = "Color"
        dt = Nothing
        con = Nothing
        cmd = Nothing
        adap = Nothing
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For SQL Server**: Try to put `()` around the `OR`s conditions, also you need to put `''` around the values `True` like this:

```
Select 
  name,logo,chair,color 
From Mytable 
Where (logo = 'True' or chair = 'True' or color = 'True')
  And name Is Not Null;
```

This assuming that `logo`, `chair`, and `color` are declared with data type `bit` (boolean).

Comment: Thanks for replay, gives error 'Gerekli bir veya daha fazla parametre için girilen değer yok' (English: no value entered for one or more required parameters)

Comment: @BilalFeyzullah - Please post the full query you tried and the code you are using to run that query, it seems like you are using parameters and pass them to the query with out any values.

Comment: @BilalFeyzullah - Since you are using ms-access, could you please try this query instead: `Select 
  name,logo,chair,color 
From Mytable 
Where (logo = <> 0 or chair <> 0 or color = <>0)
  And name Is Not Null;` And please run it in the ACCESS database  directly first before running it in your code, to ensure that it is working fine.